# Intermittent connection to ESX using VIX

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

My script (and vmrun) can't establish a reliable connection to an ESX server via VIX

Lets say I execute the script 10 times consecutively. the script will fail at VMOpen() function call 6 out of 10 times. Its the same situation with vmrun.

Initially, I was able to interface with that ESX machine for several months without a problem.
Now, i get connection problems several times an hour.

What gives?

Its not a network issue because I can access the https just fine.

VMOpen description: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix17_reference/lang/perl/functions/VMOpen.html

Comment: Are there error messages either on the console of the vmrun machine or in the log file of the ESX machine?

Comment: It's in the vmrun

Answer (score 0):

Without error logs, the next thing you could try would be a packet analyzer like WireShark. You might be able to see if TCP is closing the connection or if the application layer is shutting things down.